# Magnetic pressure on a streamplot of a Magnetic Field

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I made a plot in python of a magnetic field on sun which follows the code:

```
# Import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym

# Define the magnetic field function
def magnetic_field(x, y):
    Bx = y
    By = x
    return np.array([Bx, By])




# Set up the grid of coordinates
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Compute the magnetic field at each grid point
Bx, By = magnetic_field(X, Y)



# Set the size of the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

# Plot the magnetic field lines
plt.streamplot(X, Y, Bx, By, broken_streamlines= False)

# Set the limits of the plot
plt.xlim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)

# Add labels and title to the plot
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Magnetic Field Lines')


# Show the plot 

plt.show()
```

I want to put on it the strength of the magnetic pressure Pm=B^2/8pi arrow-shaped depending on the price.

The only thing I did was to find all the prices with a print and plot Pm in a different plot with y=0 or x=0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to add colors to the `streamplot` arrows that map onto the strength of the magnetic field at that location. You could take a similar approach to [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html) to do that.
First compute the strength of your magnetic field with `Pm=np.linalg.norm(np.array([Bx, By]),axis=0)**2/(8*np.pi)` and maps it onto the streamplot with `plt.streamplot(X, Y, Bx, By,color=Pm,broken_streamlines= False)`. See full code below and output:

```py
# Import the necessary modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym

# Define the magnetic field function
def magnetic_field(x, y):
    Bx = y
    By = x
    return Bx, By

# Set up the grid of coordinates
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Compute the magnetic field at each grid point
Bx, By = magnetic_field(X, Y)
Pm=np.linalg.norm(np.array([Bx, By]),axis=0)**2/(8*np.pi) #compute strength magnetic field

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
# Plot the magnetic field lines
strm=plt.streamplot(X, Y, Bx, By,color=Pm,broken_streamlines= False)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines)

# Add labels and title to the plot
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Magnetic Field Lines')

# Show the plot 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but I didn't mean this. 
I want to show a qyality repressentation of the measure (as an arrow) of the magnetic pressure on the diagram along x or along y with the other equal to zero. 
The bigger the magnetic pressure on a spot, the bigger the arrow.
Like 6-8 spots.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not sure I understand what you'd like to do. Could you draw by hand maybe what you're trying to get? Any example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html) close to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I want to end up in something like this plot https://1drv.ms/i/s!As0eimQGHvcXkC8fzG2ev7cATwzC?e=jlgBf5 with T the magntic tension